# Fluent Nhibernate deleting iregularity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having problems deleting a row using fluent nhibernate. If i execute the below method using either of the commented-out delete statements the test passes and says all is cool, but when i check the data base the row is still there

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteAdhesiveWithoutCascade()
    {
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            //session.Delete(session.Load<Adhesive>(8));
            //IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Adhesive WHERE ID = 8");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteAdhesiveWithoutCascade()
{
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.Delete(session.Load<Adhesive>(8));
        //IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Adhesive WHERE ID = 8");
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

or

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteAdhesiveWithoutCascade()
{
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Delete(session.Load<Adhesive>(8));
        //IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Adhesive WHERE ID = 8");
        session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should open a transation. Anyway try to use `session.Flush();` before closing the `}`

Comment: @beaumondo in any case is better use a transation.

Comment: I have updated all write operations to execute in transactions - cheers